# Invalid connector class. Check the connector configuration file(Kafka Connect Jdbc)

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to stream the data from Mysql Database to Apache kafka.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7xVG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuQ2L.png)

When I try to connect to control center , I get the following error?

> Invalid connector class. Check the connector configuration file.

Comment: I suggest you use Connect REST API since it won't hide the full error. Also look at the Connect Server logs

Answer (score 0):

From the image, I see you have a `pom.xml` and `src` folder, which means you may have cloned the JDBC Connector source code?

Instead of that, use Confluent Hub to install the *compiled* connector plugin - https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc

Alternatively, you can use Debezium to stream data from MySQL, which will more accurately capture all operations on the database.